# How to select the first item from a list

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have the following `for` loop that spits out all photos in a list:

```
{% if photos %}
{% for photo in photos %}
    {% thumbnail photo.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photo.id %}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How can I just select and display the first photo in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the first element using `.0`:

Combine it with [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag (to minimize changes):

```
{% if photos %}
{% with photo=photos.0 %}
    {% thumbnail photo.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photo.id %}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{ photos.0 }}` will be the first item. So:

```
{% if photos %}
   {% thumbnail photos.0.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="User's photos" data-ajax="{% url 'photo_increase_view' pk=photos.0.id %}"/>
   {% endthumbnail %}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to still use the `photo` variable in the template (since its more convenient than indexing every time), consider using `{% with photo=photos.0 %} {# ... #} {% endwith %}`