# How to select first item in a list

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have the following list:

```
{% for upcomming_gig in upcomming_gigs %}
{% with gig=upcomming_gig.gig %}

...

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This ends up printing the entire list of `gig` records. How can I select just the first in the list?

I have tried `{% with gig=upcomming_gig.gig.0 %}` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144595/2429989  but that results in no data...?

Comment: Just use `{{ upcoming_gig.0 }}`? Not quite sure why you want the loop or the with there... You might also want to rethink the tags, it's likely either python&django, or python/flask/jinja... unless you're using jinja with django, but I'm guessing not...

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of dictionaries, and then the key `gig` is a list of gigs, is that right? Are you using django templates or flask+jinja?

Comment: Can you print upcomming_gigs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll be best to do these kind of things on the server side but I guess (didn't try) this will work for django, don't know anything about Jinja

```
{% for upcomming_gig in upcomming_gigs %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    {# or loop.first for Jinja as Ilendi mentioned below #}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[>> More variables >>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

#### EDIT

I just saw the question you linked to, you're writing using `upcomming_gig` instead of `upcomming_gigs` (notice the `s` in the end). Try this:

```
{% if upcomming_gigs %}
    {% with gig=upcomming_gigs.0.gig %} # Instead of gig=upcomming_gigs.gig.0
        ...
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: your first answer is almost right!
the test in the if condition works if you write "if loop.first" instead of "if forloop.first".

Comment: @Ilendir Source? Is clearly states `forloop.first` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: The question doesn't clearly state if Django or Jinja should be used. forloop.first doesn't work in Jinja, but loop.first does. I think I should have stated it more clearly that I'm referring to Jinja.

Comment: Oh, I added that in my answer. Thanks!